# Zoom Fixo por Area e Ponto

Tags: javascript, html

As vezes trabalho com fluxo de processo muito grandes que tornam inviavel criar pontos de continuidade em mais fluxos.

Pensei em criar em JavaScript um visualizador de "fotos" que pudesse marcar via linha de codigo varios retangulos em todo o fluxo. Ao clicar em cada retangulo seria dado um zoom so daquela parte em toda a tela.

Ja com esse zoom, poderia criar DIVs transparentes do tipo caixas de texto explicando cada etapa do fluxo.

Por fim, ao clicar de novo em qualquer ponto voltaria a tela inicial com fluxo grande para um novo click de qualquer outro ponto que deseje detalhes.

Acho que isso dinamizaria muito a documentação de fluxos grandes!

Pense em usar o map area shape rect, mas estou meio enferrujado e nao sei como atribuir suas dimensoes ao tamanho da tela em um click sobre sua area.

Qualquer outra forma de se resolver na mesma linha de raciocinio seria de grande valia!

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: A ver se percebi: queres ter "rectangulos" na página que podem crescer para usar a página toda, e podem ter outros sub-rectangulos. É isso?

Comment: Perfeito, Sergio!

Comment: Aguardo algo que me ajude no raciocinio......